# How to copy slices in a image?

Tags: slice, dm-script

I want to make a copy of front image which contains several slice, like this:
 [image with several slices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiBaa.png)
I used imageclone function

```
image front, img
front.getfrontimage()
img=imageclone(front)
img.showimage()
```

But it only copy the first slices.
Have anyone know how to make a copy of this kind of image >"<
Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to duplicate the image (regardless how it is displayed) is via its "container" - ImageDocument. Here are the codes:

```
ImageDocument imgDoc = GetFrontImageDocument();
number DoDeepCopy = 1;
ImageDocument newDoc = imgDoc.ImageDocumentClone(DoDeepCopy);
newDoc.ImageDocumentShow();
```

If you need to manipulate individual slices then it is more complicated. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I know I should treat the image as imagedocument when I add slices in a image.

Comment: @Renfong: I don't know which GMS version you're using (always good to state this in a question), but on the latest GMS installations there is quite a few "example scripts" for linePlots in the F1 help section "Scripting/Example Scripts/Data Display" concerning linePlot type images.

Comment: @BmyGuest, I use GMS 3.20. Thanks a lot ^^ I will remember it next time.

Answer (score 1):

In extension to the accepted (correct and best) answer, it's worthwhile knowing how to come from an "image" to its imageDocument. You do this like in this example:

```
ClearResults()

image frontImg := GetFrontImage()
imageDocument frontDoc = GetFrontImageDocument()
Result( "Grapped from application:" )
Result( "\n\t Image: " + frontImg.ImageGetLabel() + "\t ID = " + frontImg.ImageGetID() )
Result( "\n\t Doc  : " + frontDoc.ImageDocumentGetName() + "\t ID = " + frontDoc.ImageDocumentGetID() )

imageDocument docFromImg = frontImg.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
Result( "\n Taken from image:" )
Result( "\n\t Doc  : " + frontDoc.ImageDocumentGetName() + "\t ID = " + docFromImg.ImageDocumentGetID() )

image imgFromDoc := frontDoc.ImageDocumentGetImage( 0 )
Result( "\n Taken from imageDocument:" )
Result( "\n\t Image: " + frontImg.ImageGetLabel() + "\t ID = " + imgFromDoc.ImageGetID() )
```

Note that an image does not necessarily *have* an imageDocument. The imageDocument is only created when the image is displayed or saved. That is why the command is called `...GetOrCreate`.

Similarly, an imageDocument may contain multiple images (or none).

This is all a bit convoluted, and it appears confusing because many of the "correct" commands following the internal class hierarchy are wrapped by simplification commands for scripting convenience.

f.e. Saving an image using `SaveSave()` takes an `image` variable, but it really needs to save an `imageDocument`. So it implicitly gets/creates one. Otherwise, the user would need to script the correct, but more 'complicated' script.
Instead of:

```
string path = "C:\\test.dm4"
image img := GetFrontImage()
img.SaveImage( path )
```

One would need:

```
string path = "C:\\test.dm4"
string handler = "Gatan Format"
image img := GetFrontImage()
imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile( handler, path )
```

Also note: While the route of using imageDocuments is the correct way, you should know that "linePlot displays" are really special. They are imageDisplay objects that may contain more than one image, whereas imageDocuments are objects which may contain more than one imageDisplay. I am pointing this out so that you know that you need to add new images to an imageDisplay to get more slices in an slice image. If you add them to an imageDocument, you will get multiple linePlot displays in a single file.

Depending on how "deep" you need to know all of this, I would recommend reading the documentation section on "image/imageDocument/imageDisplay/components" and testing things a bit. If questions remain, post them here on StackOverflow :c)